# Rails order hash by values and array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I had array of users, and array of they id's. I'm need create hash with {name => id}, but with order of id's array. As example, when i wrote:

```
keys = [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
users = User.all.where(id: keys).pluck(:name, :id).to_h
```

It's return me `{"User_1"=>2, "User_2"=>3, "User_3"=>4, "User_4"=>5, "User_0"=>1}`

But i'm need to get such thing:

```
{"User_4"=>5, "User_2"=>3, "User_1"=>2, "User_3"=>4, "User_0"=>1}
```

Is there opportunity to had such hash on where operation?

Answer (score 0):

The array of users that you get from your database is ordered by the `updated_at` column. Try this:

```
users = User.where(id: keys).order(id: :desc).pluck(:name, :id).to_h
```

Comment: As you can see, my keys array has values [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
4 Stays after 2.

Comment: I haven't noticed that. And i'm afraid that you won't get the result you need in one simple query, because of the sorting on the db layer

Comment: Maybe it is easier to find some workaround? Like adding a position column to your table for example